# API Endpoint Performance Improvement

Tags: django

I have an API Endpoint to return daily driving logs and it's scaling very poorly. I've narrowed it down to a specific property on the model called `on_duty_total`.

```
class DailyLog(models.Model):

    ... 

    @property
    def on_duty_total(self):
        # total time on-duty (statues of driving or on-duty)
        daily_log_entries = LogEntry.objects.filter(daily_log=self, status__in=["driving", "onduty"])
        total = 0

        if daily_log_entries:
            for entry in daily_log_entries:
                total = total + entry.minutes_duration

        # add time from the carry-over log entries
        for entry in self.carry_over_log_entries():
            tz_day_start = entry.tz_end_time.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

            delta = entry.tz_end_time - tz_day_start
            minutes = delta.seconds / 60
            total = total + minutes

        # remove time from log entries that carry over to the next day
        for entry in self.overage_log_entries():
            tz_day_end = entry.tz_start_time.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59)

            delta = entry.tz_end_time - tz_day_end
            minutes = delta.seconds / 60
            total = total - minutes

        return total
```

I get the data through an API using DRF:

```
class DailyLogViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DailyLogSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return DailyLog.objects.filter(driver__user=self.request.user)
```

The problem occurs because for each daily log it's getting the `on_duty_total` which needs to do a database query (first line in the method). When a user has, for example, 100 daily logs, that means 100 database queries and it just keeps getting slower and slower.

Frankly put, I'm not sure how to remedy this, and am reaching out for ideas. However, I know running a db query for each record on a computed property is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you don't actually care about returning the model and you only use it to get a sum of a field, so you could just aggregate

```
daily_log_entries = LogEntry.objects.filter(daily_log=self, status__in=["driving", "onduty"])
daily_log_entries = daily_log_entries.aggregate(Sum('minutes_duration'))
total = daily_log_entries.minutes_duration__sum
```

I'm guessing that the majority of the time spent is by returning every value from your LogEntry object which is very wasteful, this just removes that need and just does exactly what you want, as well as performing that on the database side.